# How can we use the basic statistical analysis in R to answer these questions?

Tags: self-study, descriptive-statistics

I have come across this task which refers to the the simple statictical tests, such as Student's T-test, binomial test and chi-squared.Also this task can be done with the help of descriptive statistics, but I am not sure. Honestly, I can see that I can use simple mathematical calculations to solve this problem and I cannot understand how can I use statistics here, although I guess I should. Thanks for help!
[image]

Comment: Could you indicate where the references to "the simple statistical tests" might be in this question?  I cannot see any.

Comment: I suggest that this task is about t-test or binomial test or maybe Chi-Square Test all of this I call "statistic tests". But it seems to me that this task is simply about mathematical calculations. Because I am a newcomer in statistics and R-programming I am afraid that my common sense deceives me, so I ask for some comments from users

Comment: This isn't a sample of anything and it does not ask for inference or hypothesis testing.  You are simply being asked to describe some voting data.

Comment: I could see how B, C, and D could be asking you to conduct a hypothesis test.  I think it's a somewhat odd example as written.  It says the data represent a sample of 83 people in an election.  So I guess the scenario could be something like exit-poll data, where, you, as the analyst, are trying to predict who won the election before all the votes are counted, based on the sample. ... I would interpret A as asking for using descriptive statistics.

Comment: I also suggest that Task A is about descriptive statistics, while B,C and D require to use hypothesis test, But if so, I cannot understand what kind of hyphosesis test, because I think either Students T-test  or binomial test are suitable equally

Comment: You have a contingency table of counts, so I think you should be focusing on those tests that are applicable in this situation.  That is, probably not Student's t-test.  The question in D corresponds to the null hypothesis of a test you haven't mentioned.  Hint: the design includes paired or repeated measures on the same individuals.  But I think this fact won't come into play in answering B or C.